# ECLIPSE APPCRASH WINDOWS

Tags: java, tomcat, crash

When I start my Java-Program on localhost:8081  (Tomcat), I get this error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: eclipse.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    50816486
  Fault Module Name:    MSVCR71.dll
  Fault Module Version: 7.10.3052.4
  Fault Module Timestamp:   3e561eac
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000131b0
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1045
  Additional Information 1: 7f8a
  Additional Information 2: 7f8a085c4e5875ea037589b22bfcd15b
  Additional Information 3: 80e0
  Additional Information 4: 80e05dd58d7c19aa13bbfc0dd4b503b7
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can we have more information about your setup and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Tomcat working good. I can run  all applications on Java in Eclipse. When Tomcat start page does not show up in the browser. I reinstall Java, Eclipse and Tomcat.